# Is there a general formula for $\sin( {p \over q} \pi)$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, algebraic-numbers

Virtually everyone knows the basic values of the unit circle, $\sin(\pi) = 0; \ \ \sin({\pi  \over 2}) = 1; \ \ \sin({\pi \over 3}) = {\sqrt{3} \over 2} \\$
And other values can be calculated through various identities, like $\sin({\pi \over 8}) =\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}\\$
Does there exist a general formula for $\sin({p\over q} \pi)$ for rational ${p \over q}$ as an algebraic number?

Comment: I cannot answer your question but have fun at http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/simpleTrig.html

Comment: These  are not bad !! https://math.la.asu.edu/~surgent/mat170/Exact_Trig_Values.pdf  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals

Comment: It suffices to express $\sin(\frac{1}{q}\pi) = \operatorname{Im} e^{i\pi/q}$ in the desired form, since $\sin(\frac{p}{q}\pi) = \operatorname{Im}(e^{i\pi/q})^{p}$. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Cyclotomic_fields), roots of unity can be expressed using only the four arithmetic operations and extraction of radicals, but my non-expert suspicion is the specifics are complicated to write down for a general $q$.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Too long for a comment ...

Perusing the ["Exact Values [...] in Increments of 3 Degrees"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507003003/https://math.la.asu.edu/%7Esurgent/mat170/Exact_Trig_Values.pdf) list that [@Claude referenced](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539882/is-there-a-general-formula-for-sin-p-over-q-pi/1541219#comment3135661_1539882) (the main idea is to use the known valus for $\sin\frac{\pi}{3}$, $\sin\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\sin\frac{\pi}{5}$ and combining them using the sine addition formula), I found that the sines have this common (if not-necessarily-insightful) form:
$$\sin \left(k\cdot 3^\circ\right) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\;\sqrt{\;4\;\pm_1\;\sqrt{\phi\,(a\phi+b\overline{\phi})}\;\pm_2\;\sqrt{\overline{\phi}\,(c\phi+d\overline{\phi})}\;}$$
where $\phi := \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}+1)$ and $\overline{\phi} := \phi^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5}-1)$ are the [golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) and its reciprocal.

$$\begin{array}{r|cccccc}
\theta\; & \pm_1 & a & b & \pm_2 & c & d \\
\hline
 0^\circ & - & 16 & 0 & + & 0 & 16 \\
 3^\circ & - &  3 & 0 & - & 1 &  1 \\
 6^\circ & - &  3 & 3 & - & 0 &  1 \\
 9^\circ & - &  4 & 4 & - & 0 &  0 \\
12^\circ & - &  1 & 0 & - & 3 &  3 \\
15^\circ & - & 12 & 0 & + & 0 & 12 \\
18^\circ & - &  4 & 0 & + & 0 &  0 \\
21^\circ & - &  1 & 1 & - & 0 &  3 \\
24^\circ & - &  3 & 3 & + & 0 &  1 \\
27^\circ & + &  0 & 0 & - & 4 &  4 \\
30^\circ & - &  4 & 0 & + & 0 &  4 \\
33^\circ & - &  3 & 0 & + & 1 &  1 \\
36^\circ & + &  0 & 0 & - & 0 &  4 \\
39^\circ & - &  1 & 1 & + & 0 &  3 \\
42^\circ & + &  1 & 0 & - & 3 &  3 \\
45^\circ & + &  0 & 0 & + & 0 &  0 
\end{array}$$
$\sin(90^\circ-\theta)$ uses the same $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ as $\sin \theta$, but each of $\pm_1$ and $\pm_2$ is inverted. For instance,
$$\begin{align}
\sin 24^\circ &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\;\sqrt{\;4\;-\;\sqrt{\phi\,(3\phi+3\overline{\phi})}\;+\;\sqrt{\overline{\phi}\,(0\phi+1\overline{\phi})}\;} \\[6pt]
\sin 66^\circ &= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\;\sqrt{\;4\;+\;\sqrt{\phi\,(3\phi+3\overline{\phi})}\;-\;\sqrt{\overline{\phi}\,(0\phi+1\overline{\phi})}\;}
\end{align}$$

---

For $\theta = 0^\circ$, $30^\circ$, $45^\circ$, $60^\circ$, $90^\circ$, these reduce to a commonly-known pattern:

$$\begin{align}
\sin  0^\circ = \sqrt{\;\color{red}{0}\;}/2 \\
\sin 30^\circ = \sqrt{\;\color{red}{1}\;}/2 \\
\sin 45^\circ = \sqrt{\;\color{red}{2}\;}/2 \\
\sin 60^\circ = \sqrt{\;\color{red}{3}\;}/2 \\
\sin 90^\circ = \sqrt{\;\color{red}{4}\;}/2 \\
\end{align}$$

This is a subset of the cases in which $ab=cd=a-d=0$, which can be written in this form (noting that we happen to have $a=d=4n$):
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \sqrt{\;4\;\pm\;\sqrt{\phi\cdot 4n \phi}\;\mp\;\sqrt{\overline{\phi}\cdot 4n \overline{\phi}}\;} \;=\; \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\;2\;\pm\;(\phi-\overline{\phi})\sqrt{n}\;} \;=\; \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\;2\;\pm\;\sqrt{n}\;}$$
so that we have
$$\begin{align}
\sin 0^\circ &= \sqrt{\;2-\sqrt{\color{red}{4}}\;}\;/2 \\
\sin 15^\circ &= \sqrt{\;2-\sqrt{\color{red}{3}}\;}\;/2 \\
\color{blue}{\sin 22.5^\circ} &= \sqrt{\;2-\sqrt{\color{red}{2}}\;}\;/2 \\ 
\sin 30^\circ &= \sqrt{\;2-\sqrt{\color{red}{1}}\;}\;/2 \\
\sin 45^\circ &= \sqrt{\;2-\sqrt{\color{red}{0}}\;}\;/2 \\
\sin 60^\circ &= \sqrt{\;2+\sqrt{\color{red}{1}}\;}\;/2 \\
\color{blue}{\sin 67.5^\circ} &= \sqrt{\;2+\sqrt{\color{red}{2}}\;}\;/2 \\ 
\sin 75^\circ &= \sqrt{\;2+\sqrt{\color{red}{3}}\;}\;/2 \\
\sin 90^\circ &= \sqrt{\;2+\sqrt{\color{red}{4}}\;}\;/2 \\
\end{align}$$
with $22.5^\circ$ and $67.5^\circ$ thrown in to complete the pattern attributed to Ernesto La Orden on [Ron Knott's page](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/simpleTrig.html).

The multiples of $9^\circ$ (excluding $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$) are characterized by having one or the other (or both) of the inner radicals vanish (that is, $(a+b)(c+d)=0$). These lead to more reductions from Knott's page, although the collection lacks the kind of "counting" pattern shown above.

---

**Update.** Inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2696196/409), which lists cosines of multiples-of-$3^\circ$ without using an outer square root, I've devised this unified form:

$$\sin(k\cdot 3^\circ) = \frac{m \sqrt{n}}{4}
\left(\; 
( a\psi + b\overline{\psi} ) 
\sqrt{\phi\,( e\phi + f\overline{\phi} )} \;+\; 
( c\psi + d\overline{\psi} ) 
\sqrt{\overline{\phi}\,( g\phi + h\overline{\phi} )}
\;\right)
$$
where
$$
\{\phi,\overline{\phi}\} := \frac12\left(\sqrt{5}\pm 1\right) \quad 
\{\psi,\overline{\psi}\} := \frac12\left(\sqrt{3}\pm 1\right)$$
(with the overlined character using the "$-$").

$$\begin{array}{r|cc|cc:cc|cc:cc}
\theta\; & m & n & a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h \\
\hline
 0^\circ & 2 & 1 & + & - & - & + & 0 & + & + & \color{red}{0} \\
\hline
 3^\circ & 1 & 2 & 0 & - & + & 0 & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
 6^\circ & 1 & 1 & - & + & + & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
 9^\circ & 1 & 2 & + & - & - & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
12^\circ & 1 & 1 & + & - & - & - & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
\hdashline
\star\;15^\circ & 1 & 2 & 0 & + & 0 & + & 0 & + & + & \color{red}{0} \\
\hline
18^\circ & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & + & - & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
\hline
21^\circ & 1 & 2 & 0 & - & + & 0 & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
24^\circ & 1 & 1 & + & + & - & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
27^\circ & 1 & 2 & + & - & - & + & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
\hdashline
\star\; 30^\circ & 1 & 1 & + & - & + & - & 0 & + & + & \color{red}{0} \\
\hdashline
33^\circ & 1 & 2 & 0 & + & + & 0 & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
\hline
36^\circ & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & + & - & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
\hline
39^\circ & 1 & 2 & + & 0 & 0 & - & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
42^\circ & 1 & 1 & + & + & - & + & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
\hdashline
\star\;45^\circ & 1 & 2 & + & - & + & - & 0 & + & + & \color{red}{0} \\
\hdashline
48^\circ & 1 & 1 & + & - & + & + & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
51^\circ & 1 & 2 & 0 & + & + & 0 & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
\hline
54^\circ & 2 & 1 & + & - & 0 & 0 & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
\hline
57^\circ & 1 & 2 & + & 0 & 0 & - & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
\hdashline
\star\; 60^\circ & 1 & 1 & + & + & + & + & 0 & + & + & \color{red}{0} \\
\hdashline
63^\circ & 1 & 2 & + & - & + & - & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
66^\circ & 1 & 1 & + & - & + & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
69^\circ & 1 & 2 & + & 0 & 0 & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
\hline
72^\circ & 2 & 1 & + & - & 0 & 0 & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
\hline
\star\; 75^\circ & 1 & 2 & + & 0 & + & 0 & 0 & + & + & \color{red}{0} \\
\hdashline
78^\circ & 1 & 1 & + & + & + & - & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
81^\circ & 1 & 2 & + & - & + & - & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
84^\circ & 1 & 1 & + & + & + & - & + & \color{red}{0} & + & + \\
87^\circ & 1 & 2 & + & 0 & 0 & + & + & + & \color{red}{0} & + \\
\hline 
90^\circ & 2 & 1 & + & - & + & - & 0 & + & + & \color{red}{0}
\end{array}$$

Some observations:

- $n$ alternates $1$ and $2$.
- $m=2$ at, and only at, multiples of $18^\circ$. Everywhere else, $m=1$.
- There are only three $(e,f,g,h)$ patterns: $\alpha := (0++0)$, $\beta:=(++0+)$, $\gamma := (+0++)$. They cycle $\alpha\beta\gamma\gamma\beta\alpha\beta\gamma\gamma\beta\ldots$. (Observe the zig-zagging red "$0$" in the $(e,f,g,h)$ columns.)
- In particular, the $(e,f,g,h)$ patterns of complementary angles match.
- Except as marked with $\star$, $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ for $\theta$ are $\pm(c,d)$ and $\pm(a, b)$ for $90^\circ-\theta$, with one "$+$" and one "$-$". For those marked $\star$ (aka, the non-extreme multiples of $15^\circ$), there's no clear pattern. *Is there an unambiguous, unified relation between expressions for complementary angles?* (It was *so easy* in the earlier table!)
- Beware: I already caught (and fixed) one typo in the table.

Comment: this is amazing :))))

Answer (score 4):

There is not so much a formula, as there is an algorithm, due to Gauss. In his [*Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=PPN235993352|LOG_0011&physid=PHYS_0416) (sorry, I couldn't find a free English translation), he gives a number-theoretic view of the roots of unity (and thus, trigonometric functions). In particular, he outlines in [one section](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235993352?tify=%7B"pages":[453],"view":"fulltext"%7D) a recursive method for determining explicit radical expressions of roots of unity.

Modern methods that improve on the asymptotic complexity of Gauss's algorithm exist, however. In [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1145/240065.240070), A. Weber presents an improvement of Gauss's original algorithm that hinges on an efficient way to evaluate the "recursive step" in the original method. A Maple implementation of this improved method is presented in the paper.