# Is it just a coincidence or is it related to how values of sine calculated?

Tags: trigonometry

Actually, one of my math teacher told me about this. I want to know is there any relationship between this trick and their respective values?

[image]

Comment: Sin and cos mirror eachother because they are co-functions. One value depends on the other due to $sin^2(x) + cos^2(x) = 1$. As for the values themselves, there is no relation. It just so happens a trick could be made for those 5 values.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539882/is-there-a-general-formula-for-sin-p-over-q-pi/1541219#1541219) shows patterns for some other sets of angles.

Comment: The [Math Forum](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53929.html) shows how to derive those angles.

Answer (score 2):

It is a nice trick, but it works only for 5 listed values.