# An elegant way to solve $\frac {\sqrt3 - 1}{\sin x} + \frac {\sqrt3 + 1}{\cos x} = 4\sqrt2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The question  is to find $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$:

$$\frac {\sqrt3 - 1}{\sin x}  + \frac {\sqrt3  + 1}{\cos x} = 4\sqrt2 $$

What I did was to take the $\cos x$  fraction    to the right and try to simplify ;

But it looked very messy and trying to write $\sin x$  in terms of $\cos x$ didn't help.

Is there a more simple (elegant) way to do this.

Comment: divide both sides by $2\sqrt{2}$ and use the fact that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{6}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{6}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: $\sin \frac \pi6$ is $\frac 12$, did you mean $\frac \pi{12}$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\sin(\frac{\pi}{12}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{12}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2\sqrt{2}}$. Plugging them into your equation yields $\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{12}) = \sin(2x)$. So $x = \frac{\pi}{12}$

Comment: It $\pi/12$ not $\pi/6$

Comment: yes edited accordingly

Answer (score 8):

Another approach is to write the equation as

$(\sqrt{3} - 1) \cos x +(\sqrt{3} + 1) \sin x = 4 \sqrt2 \sin x \cos x$

then rearranging gives

$\frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \cos x +\frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \sin x = 2  \sin x \cos x$.

Now note that $(\frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{2 \sqrt{2}})^2 +(\frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{2 \sqrt{2}})^2 = \frac{1}{8} ((3 -2 \sqrt{3} + 1) + (3 +2 \sqrt{3} + 1) = 1$ so that we can write $\frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$ as the $\sin$ of some angle, say $\alpha$, and identify $\frac{\sqrt{3} + 1}{2 \sqrt{2}}$ as $\cos \alpha$.

Then you have to solve $\sin(\alpha + x) = \sin(2x)$, with $\tan \alpha = \frac{\sqrt{3} - 1}{\sqrt{3} + 1}$.

Answer (score 5):

Replace $\sqrt3=\tan60^\circ,1=\tan45^\circ$

to find $$\sin(15^\circ+x)=2\sin x\cos x=\sin2x$$

Now if $\sin y=\sin A, y=n180^\circ+(-1)^nA$ where $n$ is any integer

As $\sqrt3-1=\tan60^\circ-\tan45^\circ=\dfrac{\sin(60-45)^\circ}{\cos60^\circ\cos45^\circ}=2\sqrt2\sin15^\circ$

Similarly, $\sqrt3+1=2\sqrt2\sin75^\circ=2\sqrt2\cos15^\circ$

Comment: @user307178, Please follow the last two lines

Comment: Thanks got it...My reputation is less so I can't upvote

Comment: @user307178, I actually tried to derive the sine/cosine value of $$\dfrac{\sqrt3\pm1}{2\sqrt2}$$ without assuming them.

Comment: And I have learned a useful method to derive them! Because I always forget it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know a similar  trick to get sin18°?  That would  be awesome

Comment: @user307178, http://openstudy.com/updates/4faf24d0e4b059b524fa3ba2   OR https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/The_sine_of_18_degrees OR http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/cos36.shtml

Comment: @user307178: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1541219/409) gives a common (if un-memorable) form for sines and cosines of multiples of $3^\circ$.

Comment: @Blue A very nice pattern in the end for the common multiples. Excellent  answer.