# $\sin(\alpha) = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{k}$, where $n$ and $k$ are integers and $\alpha$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, radicals

It is well known that the solutions of the equation

$$
\sin\left(\frac\pi x\right)= \frac{\sqrt3}{2}
$$

are

$$
x=\frac{3}{6n+2}, n\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

and

$$
x=\frac{3}{6n+1}, n\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

> Are there any other known values $\alpha$ such that $\sin(\alpha) = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{k}$, where $k$ and $n$ are positive integers and $\alpha$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$?

Comment: You meant $\sqrt{n}/k$, right?

Comment: How $3=\frac3 {6\cdot 3+1}$ or $3=\frac3 {6\cdot 3+2}$?

Comment: When $k,n$ are positive integers, $k\sqrt{n}>1$ unless $k,n=1.$

Comment: I think OP means $x=\frac{3}{6n+2}, \frac{3}{6n+1}$ for integer  values of $n.$ @user

Comment: I think you probably don't mean to require $k$ to be an integer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It would make sense.

Comment: It's not clear what kind of answer you're looking for. If $0<k\sqrt n<1$, there is exactly one value between $0$ and $\pi/2$ that has that number as its sine.

Comment: @J.G. True, edited

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, thank you, I edited the question

Comment: Don't forget $\sin(\pi/4) = \sqrt{2}/2$ and $\sin(\pi/2) = \sqrt{4}/2$. There's also $\sin 0 = \sqrt{0}/2$, but writing this argument as $\pi/x$ is problematic. (I realize you asked for $k$ to be *positive*. Still, why not just write $\sin(\pi x)$?) That said, you can take any integer $k$ and $n$ you like, with $k\leq n^2$, and the corresponding $\alpha$ is simply $\arcsin(\sqrt{k}/n)$; that's rarely a *nice* number, though. Are you specifically interested in $\alpha$ being a *rational* multiple of $\pi$? ([This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1539882/409) asks something similar.)

Comment: @Blue Thank you for your comment, yes that's exactly what I'm looking for, i.e., a *rational* multiple of $\pi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sine is a continuous function, it will take any value $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{k}$ such as $-1\le\frac{\sqrt{n}}{k}\le 1$. (I assumed that you ment $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{k}$ based on your example).

Comment: Can you give any specific values? That is what I'm looking for

Comment: @Klangen: Well, we have $\sin \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ but for any value $a$ that falls into $[-1,1]$ interval you can just take $\sin^{-1} a$