# Is there a simple pattern to memorize the sine of $0^\circ$, $15^\circ$, $30^\circ$, $45^\circ$, $60^\circ$, $75^\circ$, $90^\circ$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

We know there is a nice pattern to memorize the sine of $0^\circ$, $30^\circ$, $45^\circ$, $60^\circ$,  $90^\circ$ as follows.

\begin{align}
\sin 0^\circ &= \tfrac12\sqrt0\\
\sin 30^\circ &= \tfrac12\sqrt1\\
\sin 45^\circ &= \tfrac12\sqrt2\\
\sin 60^\circ &= \tfrac12\sqrt3\\
\sin 90^\circ &= \tfrac12\sqrt4
\end{align}

We also know that

\begin{align}
\sin 15^\circ &= \tfrac14(\sqrt6-\sqrt2)\\
\sin 75^\circ &= \tfrac14(\sqrt6+\sqrt2)
\end{align}

## Question

If I want to combine these two groups, is there a simple nice pattern available for us to easily rote memorize them?

Comment: (+1) for this nice pattern, I was not aware of.

Comment: The sines below apparently do not fit in the pattern above.

Comment: One way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTGhCGrPLmw - Not sure if it helps.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you want, but it shows a way of how the values were derived...:)

Comment: The "Nice" pattern you start with is itself less nice than it first appears. Because the gaps between the angles are $30^\circ, 15^\circ, 15^\circ, 30^\circ$, what first seems like a nice pattern suddenly is revealed to be more of a "pick out the values we like" pattern (though one with some symmetry).

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1541219/409), I give a unified form for sines of multiples of $3^\circ$. No particularly "nice" patterns, though.

Comment: @Blue: great info, entirely covers my small answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm, this pattern works:

$$
\sin 0^{\circ} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4}}, \\
\sin 15^{\circ} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}, \\
\color{gray}{\sin 22.5^{\circ} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}},} \\
\sin 30^{\circ} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{1}}, \\
\sin 45^{\circ} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{0}}, \\
\sin 60^{\circ} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{1}}, \\
\color{gray}{\sin 67.5^{\circ} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}},} \\
\sin 75^{\circ} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}, \\
\sin 90^{\circ} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{4}}.
$$

Comment: Brilliant! That's why Maths are beautiful

Comment: "... of which fact you have discovered a truly marvelous sequence.  The narrowness of this margin doesn’t permit [you to include the steps]."

Answer (score 3):

This answer is inspired from Oleg567's answer. (I should say, I will explain why does this beautiful sequence appears.)

Firstly we know that: (It should be the **really** amazing and beautiful sequence)
$$\cos 0^\circ=\dfrac{\sqrt{4}}{2}\quad\cos 30^\circ=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\quad\cos 45^\circ=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\\cos 60^\circ=\dfrac{\sqrt{1}}{2}\quad\cos 90^\circ=\dfrac{\sqrt{0}}{2}\quad\cos 120^\circ=-\dfrac{\sqrt{1}}{2}\\\cos 135^\circ=-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\quad\cos 150^\circ=-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\quad\cos 180^\circ=-\dfrac{\sqrt{4}}{2}\\$$
Then, we'll use the [half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae) $\sin^2 \dfrac{\theta}{2} = \dfrac{1-\cos\theta}{2}$

$\because 0^\circ \le\theta\le 180^\circ \rightarrow 0^\circ \le\dfrac{\theta}{2}\le 90^\circ \\ \therefore \sin \dfrac{\theta}{2} = \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos\theta}{2}}\ge 0 \\ \text{The }\cos\theta\text{ we want are all in the form }\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\text{ where }n=0,1,2,3,4 \\ \quad\sin \dfrac{\theta}{2}\\=\sqrt{\dfrac{1\mp\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}}{2}}\\=\sqrt{\dfrac{2\mp\sqrt{n}}{4}}\\=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\mp\sqrt{n}}$

Therefore, we get the the result below:
$$\sin 0^\circ=\sin \dfrac{1}{2}\left(0^\circ\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4}}\quad\sin 15^\circ=\sin \dfrac{1}{2}\left(30^\circ\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\\\sin 22.5^\circ=\sin \dfrac{1}{2}\left(45^\circ\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}\quad\sin 30^\circ=\sin \dfrac{1}{2}\left(60^\circ\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{1}}\\\sin 45^\circ=\sin \dfrac{1}{2}\left(90^\circ\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\mp\sqrt{0}}\quad\sin 60^\circ=\sin \dfrac{1}{2}\left(120^\circ\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{1}}\\\sin 67.5^\circ=\sin \dfrac{1}{2}\left(135^\circ\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\quad\sin 75^\circ=\sin \dfrac{1}{2}\left(150^\circ\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}\\\sin 90^\circ=\sin \dfrac{1}{2}\left(180^\circ\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{4}}$$