# Two mysterious missing angles in the sine values of acute angle list?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

There is a well known list of 5 for  trig values of special angles between 0$^o$ to $90^o$:

$\sin 0^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{blue}{0}}}{2}$, $\sin 30^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{blue}{1}}}{2}$
, $\sin 45^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{blue}{2}}}{2}$
, $\sin 60^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{blue}{3}}}{2}$, $\sin 90^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{blue}{4}}}{2}$

If wee add 15$^o$ and 75$^o$ , we can  make the angles evenly spaced by 15$^o$ and expand the list of 5 to a list of 7:

$\sin 0^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{blue}{0}}}{2}$,$\sin 15^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{red}{2-\sqrt3}}}{2}$, $\sin 30^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{blue}{1}}}{2}$
, $\sin 45^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{blue}{2}}}{2}$
, $\sin 60^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{blue}{3}}}{2}$,$\sin 75^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{red}{2+\sqrt 3}}}{2}$, $\sin 90^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{blue}{4}}}{2}$

Reformat the list :

$\sin 0^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{green}{2-\sqrt {4}}}}{2}$,$\sin 15^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{green}{2-\sqrt3}}}{2}$, $\sin 30^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{green}{2-\sqrt{1}}}}{2}$

, $\sin 45^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{green}{2-\sqrt{0}}}}{2}$
, $\sin 60^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{green}{2+\sqrt{1}}}}{2}$,$\sin 75^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{green}{2+\sqrt 3}}}{2}$, $\sin 90^o =\frac{\sqrt {\color{green}{2+\sqrt{4}}}}{2}$

Now, we see a nice pattern of **$\frac{\sqrt {{2\color{red}{\pm}\sqrt i}}}{2}$** with i=0,1,3,4.

But wait, why is 2 missing from this i list?  Seems like we have two special angles lost. With them, we can expand this to list of 9. Where are these two mysterious angles?  Can you find them and prove they  fit into the pattern? Or, do you find ways to expand this list even further to a list of 11,13,...and find something amazing?

Comment: $\sin(22.5) = \frac {\sqrt{2-\sqrt 2}}2$

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1541219/409), which includes the missing values and goes on to give a common form for sines of all multiples of $3^\circ$. Perhaps you can complete the task of finding a pattern there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing angles are:

$$\sin 22.5º = \frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt2}}{2}$$
$$\sin 67.5º = \frac{\sqrt{2 + \sqrt2}}{2}$$

There are other values listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Special_values) on Wikipedia, but the pattern is not obvious. For instance, $\sin 18º = \frac{\sqrt5 - 1}{4}$, but $\arcsin \frac{\sqrt5 + 1}{4}$ is not $90º - 72º = 36º$ but $54º$. In fact, $\sin 36º = \frac{\sqrt{10 - \sqrt{20}}}{4}$ and $\sin 72º = \frac{\sqrt{10 + \sqrt{20}}}{4}$.

The nice numbers for the sines of multiples of $18º$ come from the fact that $\sin (3\pi/10) = \cos (2 \pi/10)$, and solving $\sin(3x) = \sin(2x)$  using the triple-angle and double-angle formulas gives a nice quadratic in disguise after substituting $u = x^2$. The formulas involving $\sin(4x)$ and so on do not reduce into quadratics, and so if they can be reduced into radicals at all, the forms will be more complicated.

Comment: I don't have to calculate it to know that $\sqrt{10-\sqrt{20}} = 4\sin 36^\circ = \sqrt{10+\sqrt{20}}$ is not incorrect

Comment: @user253751 Thanks for spotting the typo: the other one is $\sin 72º$.